# How to estimate inductive coupling between distant air coils

Tags: inductance, solenoid

I have two air coils. They both have diameter **d**. There is a distance **D** between their centres.

**D** is much greater than **d** (more than 10x greater)

Both coils are at different angles, **a** and **b**, relative to the line between their centers. There is an alternating current in one coil.

Is there some simple function which estimates the current induced in the second coil?  I would be happy if the form of the function was:

k * f(D, a, b)   (where k had to be measured)

For example: k * cos(a) * cos(b) * D^-2

Comment: This question is more appropriate for a physics forum than it is for here. Although it's still a fun problem.

Comment: My guess is that it would be more something like `k * cos(a-b) * D^-2`

Comment: ... assuming a spherical cow on a frictionless surface ...

Comment: This is not homework. I do not go to school, as I am 33 years old.

Comment: wouldn't the field strength from solenoids fall off more quickly than inverse-square, since the source more resembles a dipole than a point?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - That's no reason not to go to school!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for Ampere's law and Faraday's law, parts of Maxwell's equations.

For a distance D between coils much greater than the coil diameter,
The *voltage* induced on the second coil from a given *current* on the input coil is something like

- Vout = 2 π f N S Bo cos b,

where

- f = carrier frequency of transmitted signal in Hz
- N = number of turns in the receiving output coil
- S = area of output loop in m^2
- Bo = strength of the arrival magnetic field
- b = angle of the output coil away from "axis pointing directly at input coil"

and in turn,

- Bo = μ0 I N R^2 cos a / ( 2( R^2 + D^2 )^3/2 ),

where

- μ0 = the universal permeability of free space
- I = current in input wire
- N = number of turns in the transmitting coil
- R = radius of transmitting coil
- D = distance between the coils
- a = angle of the transmitting coil axis away from "axis pointing directly at output coil"

At long distances, the magnetic field (and hence the produced voltage) drops off with D^(-3).

- ["Microchip AN678: RFID Coil Design"](http://microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en011766)
- ["Microchip microID(R) 125 kHz RFID System Design Guide"](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51115F.pdf)